# SQL Query Sum up Values Actual Year to Date and What the Average YTD

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I need a query that, totals up expenses Actual YTD, Average YTD( out of all the years , what is my average year), Last Year YTD

I need 3 pieces of Data:     Actual YTD |  Average YTD |  Last Years|

This is what I have so far:

```
select  SUM(Expenses)
        ,DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,[Date]), 0) 
from    table1 
group by  
        DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,[Date]), 0) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @currentYear int
SELECT @currentYear = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,[date]) = @currentYear 
    THEN Expenses ELSE 0 END) AS 'Actual YTD',
SUM(Expenses) / COUNT( DISTINCT DATEPART(year,[date])) AS 'Average YTD',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,[date]) = @currentYear -1 
    THEN Expenses ELSE 0 END) AS 'Last Year YTD'

FROM Table1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58561/8)

Comment: made one improvement, where you hard coded the 2012 Year(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(getdate())-1),getdate()),101))

Comment: Good point from you! And a DATEPART(date, getdate()) is even easier. I just simple edit it now.

Comment: Oh, ya...thats what i was looking for, tired of writing the long piece of code to format the date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select 

    AVG(case when 
        [date]>=DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,getDate())-1, 0)  and 
        [date]<DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,getDate()), 0) 
        then Expenses end) 
        as average_ytd,

    sum(case when 
        [date]>=DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,getDate())-1, 0)  and 
        [date]<DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,getDate()), 0) 
        then Expenses else 0 end) 
        as actual_ytd,

    sum(case when 
        [date]>=DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,getDate())-2, 0)  and 
        [date]<DATEADD(year, datediff(year,0,getDate())-1, 0) 
        then Expenses else 0 end) 
        as lat_year_ytd
from
    table1
```

Comment: Thanks Madhivanan,  I tried it out, why would I get 0 for last years ytd there is data for 2011

Comment: Figured it out -  Last Year Date is looking between 1-2010 - 1- 2011. Thanks for the help.